# "Challenging Geometry Conundrum: Proving the Cyclicity of Quadrilateral EYFZ"

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, trigonometry

Problem:

In triangle $ ABC $, let $ O $ be the circumcenter, and $ I $ be the incenter. The triangle’s incircle touches sides $ BC $, $ CA $, and $ AB $ at points $ D $, $ E $, and $ F $, respectively. Let $ M $ be the midpoint of side  $BC$ , and $ H $ be the orthocenter of triangle $ ABC $. The circumcircle of triangle $BIC $ intersects the incircle of $ ABC $ again at point $ X $ different from  $D$ . The line through $X $ parallel to  $BC$  intersects  $AB$  and $ AC $ at $ Y $ and $ Z $, respectively.

Question:

Prove that the quadrilateral  $EYFZ$  is cyclic, and its circumcircle is tangent to the circumcircle of triangle  $ABC$ .

My Attempt

I've spent quite some time grappling with this intriguing geometry problem, but unfortunately, it seems to have me stumped.

Initially, I attempted to approach the problem by considering the properties of the circumcircle of triangle  BIC  and its intersection with the incircle of triangle  ABC . I thought that understanding the relationship between these circles might shed some light on the configuration of points  X ,  Y , and  Z . However, despite my efforts to analyze the angles and intersections involved, I couldn't seem to discern a clear pattern.

Next, I turned my attention to the construction of points  Y  and  Z , which are formed by drawing a line through X  parallel to  BC and intersecting with  AB  and AC , respectively. I thought perhaps exploring the properties of these points might offer some insight into the cyclicity of quadrilateral EYFZ . Yet, no matter how I approached the problem, I couldn't seem to make the necessary connections.

As I continued to wrestle with the problem, I couldn't shake the feeling of frustration that was beginning to creep in. Each attempted approach seemed to lead me further into a maze of geometric complexities, with no clear path forward. Despite my best efforts to dissect the problem from various angles, I found myself unable to unlock its secrets.

In the end, after exhausting numerous avenues of investigation, I reluctantly concluded that this problem may be beyond my current level of geometric expertise. While I'm disappointed not to have found a solution, I recognize that some problems are simply more challenging than others. So is there someone who can give me some ideas that I am not looking upon and help me solve this problem.

Comment: Can you add a diagram? I do not see how "The circumcircle of triangle $BIC $ intersects the incircle of $ ABC $ again at point $ X $ different from  $D$ . " The circumcircle of triangle $BIC$ doesn't go through point $D$.